# How to sort by range category?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Name | Score | Age  |
+------+-------+------+
| Sam  |    90 |   10 |
| Kim  |    85 |   12 |
| Tom  |    60 |   10 |
| Tim  |    86 |   10 |
| Lucy |    95 |   11 |
| Jack |    80 |    9 |
| John |    62 |   11 |
+------+-------+------+
```

I want to map the score to grade 'A'(90-100),'B'(80-89),'C'(<80) and then sort by grade (ASC) and age (ASC) using MySql. So the result should look like this:

```
+------+-------+------+-------+
| Name | Score | Age  | Grade |
+------+-------+------+-------+
| Sam  |    90 |   10 |   A   |
| Lucy |    95 |   11 |   A   |
| Jack |    80 |    9 |   B   |
| Tim  |    86 |   10 |   B   |
| Kim  |    85 |   12 |   B   |
| Tom  |    60 |   10 |   C   |
| John |    62 |   11 |   C   |
+------+-------+------+-------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE for examlple IF condition  OR A CASE wHEN like in the example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE grades (
>   `Name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `Score` INTEGER,
>   `Age` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO grades
>   (`Name`, `Score`, `Age`)
> VALUES
>   ('Sam', '90', '10'),
>   ('Lucy', '95', '11'),
>   ('Kim', '85', '12'),
>   ('Tim', '86', '10'),
>   ('Jack', '80', '9'),
>   ('Tom', '60', '10'),
>   ('John', '62', '11');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   g.*
>   , IF(Score <= 100  AND Score >= 90,'A',IF(Score >= 80  AND Score <= 89,'B','C')) Grade
> FROM grades g
> ORDER BY Grade ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | Score | Age | Grade
> :--- | ----: | --: | :----
> Sam  |    90 |  10 | A    
> Lucy |    95 |  11 | A    
> Kim  |    85 |  12 | B    
> Tim  |    86 |  10 | B    
> Jack |    80 |   9 | B    
> Tom  |    60 |  10 | C    
> John |    62 |  11 | C
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   g.*
>   , 
>   CASE WHEN Score <= 100  AND Score >= 90 THEN'A'
>   WHEN Score >= 80  AND Score <= 89 THEN 'B'
>   ELSE 'C'
>   END Grade
> FROM grades g
> ORDER BY Grade ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | Score | Age | Grade
> :--- | ----: | --: | :----
> Sam  |    90 |  10 | A    
> Lucy |    95 |  11 | A    
> Kim  |    85 |  12 | B    
> Tim  |    86 |  10 | B    
> Jack |    80 |   9 | B    
> Tom  |    60 |  10 | C    
> John |    62 |  11 | C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0a3da1508ea761f3483cce04d511f66)*